# What is a refactoring participant in words?

Tags: java, refactoring

Is there any short definition about 'participants' in the context of refactoring extensions?

[org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.RefactoringParticipant](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ltk/core/refactoring/participants/package-summary.html) talks about participants, but there is no information about *what is a participant*

Is it a person, an animal, a piece of code?

I've searched a lot, but I can't find any valid definition of what is a "participant"

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactoring participants in Eclipse make refactorings extensible. Say you want to develop an Eclipse plug-in that gets notified whenever the user renames a class and update a domain-specific XML file in response to the refactoring. Eclipse provides extension points for other plug-ins to augment Eclipse refactorings. See [The Language Toolkit: An API for Automated Refactorings in Eclipse-based IDEs](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-LTK/ltk.html#refactoring_participants) for more information.

Comment: I don't want to be fastidious, but I need a definition of _"what is"_ a participant. So... could we say that a participant _is an external plug-in which interacts with one or other Eclipse refactoring throughout an extension point_? Or have I misunderstood your information?

Comment: A refactoring participant is a class that you can write to augment the functionality of a refactoring using an extension point.